# File Drag&Drop from Browser to Browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, file-upload, drag-and-drop

My asp.net web application is some kind of "document managment system" saving files in the file system of the server. 
The stored files are shown in an asp:ListView control and are downloadable as HTTP- Download. But I also want to drag&drop them into another browser window to upload the draged file to an cloud storeage like dropbox or google drive oslt.

I did some research and I didn't find any solution for this problem. I don't know if this is even possible. Maybe someone has an idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't have a web application doing that for you because it involves having your web language interacting with your computer, to move a local file to another window or tab in the browser.

It would be similar to have Javascript accessing your local files without the user "help". That is not allowed.

Rather than doing that, why not connect to Google Drive or Dropbox API and make the upload yourself?

In the piece of code where you trigger the download, you could also trigger an upload to the desired service.

Here are the API Documentation for the mentioned services:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-create

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought it may be possbile because it is possible from the local file system and maybe there is an way to bind the file location in the local network in a similar way to the js-event. 
Dropbox and Google Drive are just examples, the actual cloud storage provider is  self made by an financial institute and does not have an API.

Comment: Oh I see...without the API it makes things harder. You can always write some code to monitor your local folder and manipulate the downloaded files, but I am not sure what actually happens when you drag a local file to the browser (which is the action you would need to simulate). I would research that specific behavior (drop file in a browser), but my guess is that it is not possible :(

Comment: Ok Bruno, thank you very much. Maybe someone else has an idea but I suppose you are right thinking it is not possible.